# Passing string as a parameter

Tags: c++, string, function, c++11, reference

Want to pass as a reference. So that i can modify the string inside the function.

```
    void shift(string &s,int i){
    int len=strlen(s);
    for(;len>i;len--){
        s[len]=s[len-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: In case `string` is `std::string`, you don't need to use `strlen`, the `std::string` class provides a method for that. And also for what you actually want to do, there is an existing method you can use ...

Comment: What is `string`? Post a minimal *complete* example!

Comment: I want to shift the characters from the ith position of the string.

Comment: Well, go ahead then. What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code snippet modified to do what you're trying to achieve, with comments explaining the changes:

```
void shift(std::string &s,int i){ // use std::string (if you aren't already)
    int len=s.length(); // use length() when working with std::string
    s.resize(len+1); // before shifting the characters, you need to ensure there's enough space
    for(;len>i;len--){ // use len (not s[len]) to compare the current position to i
        s[len]=s[len-1];
    }
}
```

Of course, you could instead use std::string's existing functionality as [Rene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767436/rene) has mentioned: `s.insert(i, "_")` will do what your `shift()` function does and insert an `_` into the space created after the characters are shifted.

Comment: When i use insert() funct . It saying memory limit exceeded.

Comment: What kind of input are you passing into `insert()`? And what string `s` are you calling it on? Your "memory limit exceeded" issue might not be related to `insert()` or your `shift()` function.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    char ch;
    cin>>str;
    int len=str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(str[i]=='z'){
            str.resize(++len);
            str.insert(i," ");
        }
    }
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}

Comment: That code keeps inserting `" "` behind the first `z` it finds until it runs out of memory. After calling `insert()` (or `shift()`) you should increment `i` once to skip over the `z` you just found.